# Bad redirection after log in

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, redirection

I encountered this bug on japanese.stackexchange.com. <s>Not yet tested on other sites.</s> It seems that this is related to the presence of Japanese characters in the title of the question.

Reproduction step:

- Visit any question **with Japanese text**
- Click log in (I log in with OpenID, GMail).
- The redirection results in 404.

One example of 404 link (redirection):

```
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/11373/when-to-use-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-when-to-use-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF
```

Compared to the normal link:

```
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/when-to-use-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-when-to-use-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF
```

As you can see `questions` is missing from the link after redirection.

Comment: Humm, I can also repo this sometimes... not sure what triggers it (it doesn't seem as clear cut as your reproduction steps, as sometimes it worked fine for me).

Comment: Don't know. I repro this for 2 different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks; this related to a fix for some similar broken scenarios - looks like I took 2 steps forward but one back. I've fixed this regression now - it should be fine after the next build.

Edit: which is now